# Temporary folder WordPress on Apache2 Ubuntu

Tags: wordpress, apache2, temporary

I'm developing a new website in WordPress, the server is on my University and my problem is that I can't import a XML file. Every time I try to upload the file I get the error message that I need a temporary folder, I tried to create the temp folder on /var/www/comp/wp-content/temp with the code in my wp-config.php

```
define('WP_TEMP_DIR', dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-content/temp/');
```

but I keep getting the error. I researched for a long time, but nothing solved my problem.

Comment: check your server wp-content folder permission that may be the reason

Comment: How can i do this?

Comment: So i checked my the folder and the permission is setted  in 775

Comment: you need to check the permission of the parent folder too.

Comment: i've found my problem, the php.ini file on apache2 had a path problem on the tem dir, so i just corrected the path and everything is working